# How to inflate/ include a layout under the Toolbar up navigation?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-toolbar

I want to make a custom toolbar and I've encountered an old problem, the content of the included (or inflated) layout goes aside of the up navigation button. What I really want is to put the content below of the up button, like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55qzh.png). This seems to be not possible because of the persistent margin alongside the height of the toolbar. In this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCVZ7.png) can be observed the problem.

I've tried a workaround to put the toolbar in a LinearLayout (vertical) and to inflate the content below, but it's not the desired way. Another solution was to disable the up button and make the button in the layout, but here, the onBack needs to be handled, which is pretty hard without ActionBar support for this.
I've also tried the **contentInsetStart** and **contentInsetStartWithNavigation** attributes, but these removes only the margin before the navigation button.

Answer (score 0):

use theme with no action bar and include your layout in xml like this

```
<include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar" 
            layout="@layout/toolbar_with_search" //your layout file of toolbar
            />
```

and then find it like this in java

```
     toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.id.YourIcon);
```

i hope it will help

Comment: Thanks for the replying. This is indeed a solution that I've already tried. The problem is that I need to handle the back action carefully, because they're parent Activities which needs to be called or recreated. However, this can be solved with [NavUtils](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NavUtils.html#navigateUpFromSameTask(android.app.Activity)).

Answer (score 0):

Most official Google UI components are built to support the Material Design concepts, and what you want to do goes against the Material Design Guidelines: https://material.io/guidelines/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar

Notice that the "Metrics" section includes an image labeled "The app bar with significantly increased height for prominence", and even here the title is aligned to the right of the toolbar's navigation icon.

I believe the only way to achieve what you're looking for is to use a second view below your `Toolbar` to draw your "title" and "subtitle" yourself.

Comment: Material Design illustrate very clear the pattern, indeed. The idea with inflating a second view seems to be the easiest way to achieve the desired result (with no elevation on the Toolbar).